# Magento 2 - How to set layout to 2 columns-right instead of 1 column

Tags: magento2, layout

I did not find the solution.. Can anyone help me?

I want to change the default `1 column layout` to `2-columns-right` layout.

Answer (score 5):

you have to change inside layout xml file,

if you want to display product details page 2column left then change file is `catalog_product_view.xml`

set layout value **`layout="2columns-right"`** inside `<page>` node.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it for cms pages. You can do it by visiting magento backend. Then go to **cms >> pages >> select the page**. Then from the left bar select the design tab. Now from the "Layout" drop down on the right select the 2 columns right.

Comment: okay. and is there also a global method?

Comment: NO ,that  only apply on that particular cms page

Comment: I think what @WolfgangMüller means to ask if there is a global method to apply changes like this to all pages, and yes, there is, as given in the answer by Rakesh; via XML update.